# Dell stock buy back

Tags: stocks

Last year dell was going private by buying back all of their stock. I have one physical(on paper) share of dell and I was wondering if I was supposed to get a buyout for it. I paid about $21 for in 2007 so I don't really care about getting $13 for it I'm just curious.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should have. You should have been contacted by the company during the buyout, and if you haven't - its probably because they don't have your correct contact info. You should contact them and close this, check their [investor relations contact info here](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/uscorp1/about-dell-investor).